# Convertir en mayúsculas el texto de un models.CharField() en Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-models

¿Alguien sabría de alguna función o de cómo convertir en mayúsculas el texto obtenido de un campo mediante form?

Mi caso es este:

```
DNI = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
```

Quiero que al recoger esos campos, se hagan en mayúscula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes esta [fantástica respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502304/1468942) que hace lo que necesitas. En cocnreto, al final tu código queda así:

```
DNI = models.CharField(max_length=9, uppercase=True)
Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60, uppercase=True)
Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=60, uppercase=True)
```

Para utilizar esa función `uppercase` en el campo CharField lo haces así:

Defines tu modelo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass


class UpperCharField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.CharField)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_uppercase = kwargs.pop('uppercase', False)
        super(UpperCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(UpperCharField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if self.is_uppercase:
            return value.upper()

        return value
```

Y si te devuelve algún error de [south migration issues](http://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part4.html#keyword-arguments) hacer esto:

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [UpperCharField],
        [],
        {
            "uppercase": ["uppercase", {"default": False}],
        },
    ),
], ["^myapp\.models\.UpperCharField"])
```

Comment: Funciona estupendamente, muchas gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 3):

Para pasar los campos a mayúsculas **dentro de un Django Form** podrías usar esto:

```
from django import forms

class UpperField(forms.CharField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.upper()


class TuModeloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    DNI = UpperField()
    Nombre = UpperField()
    Apellidos = UpperField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declararlo en el modelo directamente uusando la funcion **def save()**

```
class TuModelo(models.Model):
    DNI = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.DNI = (self.DNI).uppercase()
        self.Nombre = (self.Nombre).uppercase()
        self.Apellidos = (self.Apellidos).uppercase()
        return super(TuModelo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Si te genera error puedes reemplazar la funcion .uppercase() por .upper()